# Lattice point problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A lattice point in the plane is a point with integer coordinates.Suppose that circles with radius r are drawn using all lattice points as centres.Find the smallest value of r such that any line with slope 2/5 intersects some of the circles

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you drawn a picture?  You just need $2 \times 5$ lattice points, then a bunch of lines.  When they go out of the top of the rectangle, have them come back in at the bottom.  Do you learn anything?

Comment: Yes I have drawn the same picture.I tried with co ordinate geometry.I observed that the grid follow the same pattern regarding the line of specified slope.So I considered the grid from(0,0) to (5,5).In my second attempt I came across a calculation that indicates that (3,1) is the nearest point.After that i could not proceed

Comment: Check out https://mathhelpboards.com/potw-university-students-34/problem-week-136-november-3-2014-a-13049.html?highlight=lattice.

Answer (score 2):

To get a better feel of this, think about the same question for the line $x=a$ (constant).
What did you get?

$r=\frac12$

But now the line tilts to $5y=2x+c$. Of course $r\neq 0$ because $c$ can be an irrational number. [image]

In the grid you may notice (after drawing a few lines by hand) a region considering the line outside which is redundant. The region roughly captivated by the equal circles. For example: you consider a line from the family $5y=2x+c$ outside the region, it would mean the same case as starting the line over from the origin.

Since any line of the family in this region does intersect a lattice circle, a line anywhere would definitely intersect (tangentially included) some circles if such circles are drawn over all the lattice points.

The distance of the topmost line in the worst case (tangent one) from the centers of the equal circles at $(0,0);(2,1);(5,2) = r$.

So, for the topmost line in the figure (by the "distance of a point from a line" formula) $$\frac{|5(1)-2(2)-c|}{\sqrt{29}}=\frac{|5(2)-2(5)-c|}{\sqrt{29}}=\frac{|5(0)-2(0)-c|}{\sqrt{29}}=r$$
or
$$|c|=|1-c|\implies c=\frac12$$
Thus $r=\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{29}}=\frac1{2\sqrt{29}}$.

Comment: Answer is correct

Comment: .  You wrote  For example: you consider a line from the family 5y=2x+c outside the region, it would mean the same case as starting the line over from the origin.  I can't understand this.why it is same.Can u explain pls?Thanks in advance

Comment: The region I defined is a parallelogram roughly. If you take the topmost line nearer to $(2,1)$, it'd look as if the line starts from the origin and the case would become redundant. Have a look at the area near the origin!

Comment: Reconcile how the bottom-most line leaves the origin with how the topmost line after being placed nearer to $(2,1)$ would look like.

Comment: Okay.I get u.But then why i should not consider the line where c is let say 1/2.Can u point  me where this case is considered?

Comment: You may consider the line for which $c=-\frac12$ by considering the bottom-most line instead of the topmost but then the discussion will revolve around the point $(3,1)$ instead of $(2,1)$. $r$ still is the same. Feel the symmetry here! Got it?

Comment: Approve it to allow me some points! It is of help to put a bounty in case you want a solution fast. To approve a solution, you have to go its index or whatever and tick green!